# 日付単位で、同一グループの中で最大レコードを取得する SQL

Tags: mysql

**下記リンク先内容で、さらに条件を追記したいのですが**
・下記では「同一グループの中から最大レコードを取得」していますが、ここからさらに「日付単位で」という条件を追記した場合のSQLはどう書けば良いでしょうか？

**やりたいこと**
・同じ日付の同一グループの中から最大レコードを取得
・日付が異なれば別
※日付単位で同一グループの最大レコードを取得したい

[同一グループの中で最大のレコードを取得する SQL](http://labs.timedia.co.jp/2014/10/selecting-max-record-in-group-by.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「発送を転換」したバージョンで、AND 条件を追加するだけかと思います。

以下では、`value` カラムを追加して、
`group_id` と `updated_at` でグルーピングし、`value` が最大のレコードを出力しています。

```
create table sample_table (
  id integer not null,
  group_id integer not null,
  updated_at date not null,
  value integer not null,
  comment string not null
);

insert into sample_table values ( 1, 1, '2017-01-01', 100, 'A');
insert into sample_table values ( 2, 1, '2017-01-01', 110, 'B');
insert into sample_table values ( 3, 1, '2017-01-02', 120, 'C');
insert into sample_table values ( 4, 2, '2017-01-02', 130, 'D');
insert into sample_table values ( 5, 2, '2017-01-02', 140, 'E');

select *
FROM sample_table AS m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM sample_table AS s
    WHERE m.group_id = s.group_id
    AND m.updated_at = s.updated_at
    AND m.value < s.value
);
```

結果:

```
2|1|2017-01-01|110|B
3|1|2017-01-02|120|C
5|2|2017-01-02|140|E
```

手元に mysql がなくて sqlite でやりましたが、同じだと思います。